# DocuSign Template Prefil Fields Through API

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I was a user of Right Signature, where we can create merge fields, and we can send the data through post request,

I have recently migrated to Docusign,

I see that they have prefil fields.

What I want to achieve is, Create Prefil fields, like Owner Name, Owner Email, etc,

And supply this fields through DOCUSIGN API, and send them. Is this functionality even possible.

I could not find any documentation, or perhaps I do not have the right search. Can some one point me to it, what will be the syntax for sending the templates, with prefil fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do from the web app - you can do from API.
The term "pre-fill fields" means something very specific, but I'm not sure exactly what you want.
Any field in DocuSign can be "pre-filled" such that the value is set by the sender. The field can be read-only or can be edited by the person that it is assigned to.
You can also use pre-fill fields that are specific for the sender and therefore cannot be modified by anyone except the sender.

All of this is possible with the API, I suggest you first try it with the web app to understand. You can do everything for free with a developer account - try it and see if it serves your need.

Comment: Thankyou very much for taking out the time to answer, By webapp, do you mean the website .What I am trying to acheive is, There will be common fields that will be filled by the sender, and the recipent just needs to approve and sign it.

Comment: If possible, can you point me to the api, that shows what will be the fields, api will be expecting.

Comment: Here is a code examples showing how to do this:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-envelope-tab-values/